# Import SVG image to navbar react js

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

i am struggling to describe the question i need to search so i am going to post here with the code and problem i am having and hopefully a senior front end dev could help me work it out.

So i am working on this atm... [image: Navbar]

see where it says Junodrop i would like to replace that with a logo in the shape of a SVG file so i can show that instead.

the navbar section coded logo is as follows.

````
import { Link as LinkR } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link as LinkS} from 'react-scroll'

export const Nav = styled.nav`
 background: #000;
 height: 80px; 
//  margin-top: -80px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center; 
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 1rem;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 10;

 @media screen and (max-with: 960px) {
     transition: 0.8s all ease;
 }
`;

export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 0 24px;
  max-width: 1100px;
`;

export const NavLogo = styled(LinkR)`
color: #fff;
justify-self: flex-start;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1.5rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin-left: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
`;

export const MobileIcon = styled.div`
 display: none;

 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     display: block;
     position: aboslute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     cursor: pointer; 
     color: #fff;
  }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: -22px;

 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavItem = styled.li`
  height: 80px;
`;

export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.active {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
  }
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`

export const NavBtnLink = styled(LinkR)`
  border-radius 50px;
  background: #01bf71;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  color: #010606;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #010606;
  }
`; ``` 

I am struggling how to do this with in a ``` `` ``` 

Anyone got an idea of what i need to write for this? 

p.s my svg file would be stored in ```junodrop.io/src/images```

Thank you for reading
````

Answer (score 0):

import the logo image from the folder and put it in the image src don't display a website logo from CSS background-image property it is not a good practice.

```
import Logo from "../junodrop.io/src/images"


<img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
```

or you can simply copy the SVG tag and place it directly to the website if you get an error, with some of the SVG attributes you can use an SVG optimizer something like this

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

https://svgoptimizer.com/